# How to debug Uglified code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, coffeescript, uglifier

I have coffee script in my rails project that is easy enough to turn into javascript. The js files are hosted locally in my dev environment in which they work as expected.

When I push to Heroku though, certain behaviour is not occurring (though plenty of stuff within the same file is working as expected). The console is not giving me any errors and the script I'm worried about is now merged with a bunch of other js files and uglified.

How do I find out what the problem is?

Comment: Are you using Firefox?  With the Firebug plugin, you can view the scripts in the Firebug panel, and use the '{}' button to un-minify the script, then debug with a regular step-through debugger.  It won't separate your files back out, though.  If you want to do that, you have to turn asset compilation off.

Comment: I think the problem must be in the asset compilation. I'm using chrome and I didn't know about unminifying (I've been trying to do it manually) but I'll try that...

Comment: Interesting, firefox crashes whenever I resume (Chrome does not though). Chrome indicates to me that a callback is not firing which may mean the problem is with rails' "ajax:complete" or something (which is what I was expecting to fire)

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue with coffeescript as long as you've included the `gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'` gem within your gemfile. It's most likely a compilation error. I would isolate which behaviors are not working, check why they aren't working, and then see if there are any similarities between those files that don't function properly.

Comment: The only consistency that I've found is that "ajax:complete" doesn't seem to be firing when I submit a form generated by an ajax call. This only happens on heroku, not in my local environment.